# Hardware Accelerated Image Scaling in windows using C++

Tags: c++, gpu, directx, video-capture, ms-media-foundation

I have to scale a bitmap image (e.g 1280 x 720 to 1920 X 180 and vice versa).

I am using this scaling in video capturing from screen. Software based scaling consumes lots of CPU scaling and slower as well.

Is there any hardware accelerated API or library to perform scaling?

Some methods are discussed in thread [How to use hardware video scalers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13691857/how-to-use-hardware-video-scalers?answertab=oldest#tab-top). Buts no final conclusion.

Support Needed : Windows 7 onwards

Comment: certainly there are hardware accelerated APIs to perform scaling - D3D can do it... although, without giving some details about your application and the input image, it's going to be hard to answer.

Comment: I am doing capturing with bitblt API of GDI and Direct3d9, direct3d11. one out of three is used depending upon hardware and directx support. So AFAIK it's Bitmap type image.  Please suggest D3D API or method used to scale image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a a `IDirect3DTexture9` of the image to be scaled, you can use [StretchRect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174471(v=vs.85).aspx).

There is no equivalent function in D3D11, however, if you have a `ID3D11Texture2D` of the image to be scaled, you can simply create a render target of the desired destination size, a fullscreen quad, and render to the target with a simple shader that just samples the original texture. The resulting render target will be a scaled image of the input. Note: this fullscreen quad method will also work in D3D9.

Comment: thanks @MuertoExcobito. But AFAIK StretchRect is not hardware accelerated, and it uses cpu cycles.

Comment: It is done in hardware... which is why there are so many restrictions about the source/destination resources. In particular, that documentation says "Since color conversion support is not supported by software emulation, use IDirect3D9::CheckDeviceFormatConversion to test the hardware for color conversion support.", which pretty clearly indicates that the operation is performed by the GPU.

Comment: thanks @MuertoExcobito for explanation. it is mentioned in [How to use hardware video scalers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13691857/how-to-use-hardware-video-scalers?answertab=oldest#tab-top) that it's software based. Now i understand i ll try to implement it. Thanks again.