# hardware accelerated scaling MFT in windows7

Tags: c++, windows, scaling, ms-media-foundation

I am searching hardware accelerated(GPU) based video scaling.I found a extensive discussion in following threads
[How to use hardware video scalers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13691857/how-to-use-hardware-video-scalers?answertab=oldest#tab-top)  and
[Hardware Accelerated Image Scaling in windows using C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35277510/hardware-accelerated-image-scaling-in-windows-using-c)

I try to stick with MFT based scaling because i also using *H.264 Encoder* MFT in my application.
We have two option for MFT based solution-
 1. [Video Resizer DSP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff819491(v=vs.85).aspx)
 2. [Video Processor MFT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh162913(v=vs.85).aspx)

But both these methods used [MF_SA_D3D_AWARE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh162889(v=vs.85).aspx). As mentioned below:
 ***A video MFT has the attribute [MF_SA_D3D_AWARE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh162889(v=vs.85).aspx).aspx which can be used to query whether it supports DirectX 3D hardware acceleration, and this can be enabled by sending it the MFT_MESSAGE_SET_D3D_MANAGER message.***
and MF_SA_D3D_AWARE is supported in ***Windows 8*** onwards.

Is their any MFT for scaling which uses Hardware acceleration in windows 7 ?

I haven't investigated other two options(MFCreateVideoRenderer and IDirectXVideoProcessor::VideoProcessBlt) mentioned in  [How to use hardware video scalers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13691857/how-to-use-hardware-video-scalers?answertab=oldest#tab-top) that it will support in windows 7 or not. But I am actively looking for MFT option on priority.

Answer (score 1):

Under Windows 7, i will recommand you to use [IDXVAHD_VideoProcessor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373918(v=vs.85).aspx)

You have a sample here : [DXVA-HD Sample](https://github.com/pauldotknopf/WindowsSDK7-Samples/tree/master/multimedia/mediafoundation)

But i think that if you use a simple DirectXDevice9 with a DirectXTexture9, the scaling result will be the same. There is no reason that dedicated scaling process only apply to video file process. I think they are the same for both (game and video file).

The lonely thing i saw, is that you can setup the constriction mode : [DXVAHD_BLT_STATE_CONSTRICTION_DATA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/windows/desktop/dd318394.aspx) , wich apply to downscaling, not really to upscaling.